# How to use find() called from mongoose model to get just that specific model from a collection that contains multiple models?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these specific schemas:

```
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    Name: String,
})
```

```
const StudentSchema = new Schema({
    Class: String,
    Professor: String
})
```

```
const ProfessorSchema = new Schema({
    Class: String,
    Students: Number
})
```

I produce the following models, note that the Student and Professor are extended from the Person model:

```
mongoose.model("Person", PersonSchema, "objects" )
```

```
Person.discriminator("Professor", ProfessorSchema, "objects")
```

```
Person.discriminator("Student", StudentSchema, "objects")
```

I store all of them in the same collection "objects" and when I call the find() method from any of the models I get all the objects in the collection and not just from the specific model. How can I just retrieve from the collection one specific model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this problem of getting all the documents from all models when asking just a specific one is to provide some specific arguments arguments when constructing the model.

Instead of just providing the collection name in the model:

```
Person.discriminator("Professor", ProfessorSchema, "objects")
```

You should provide a conjunct of arguments that specify the collection and the *type* attribute:

```
const baseOptions = {
    collection: "objects",
    discriminatorKey: '__type'
}
const Professor = Person.Model.discriminator("Professor", ProfessorSchema, baseOptions)
```

The default *discriminatoryKey* now has the value equal to the model name instead of its default value that is the collection name. When you use the find() method it only retrieves the type connected with the model.